# identifierForVendor or similar for watchOS (2.0+)

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

Is there any replacement for `identifierForVendor`on watchOS (2.X)? I have been reading the documentation but it doesn't look like there's any similar method for identifying the device.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: it seems that since watch0S 6.2 the identifier [was added](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacedevice/3538473-identifierforvendor?language=objc)

Comment: Awesome :), I am assigning the ticket to you now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to identify the watch. *(hand wave)*

A user can un-pair and re-pair different watches — say, to switch between a Sport for the gym and an Edition for cocktails — and from the user's point of view when interacting with software, they appear to be the same watch. (The un/re-pairing process is a bit cumbersome, but some people can and do rely on this behavior.)

If you must identify the *user*, use `identifierForVendor` on the paired iPhone (and pass it to the watch with WatchConnectivity if you need it there).

Comment: That was one of the options that we were thinking as a workaround, but we still would like to know if there's a way of getting a unique identifier of the watch itself.

Comment: Well, there's NSUUID/CFUUID for *generating* unique IDs. But there's no API in watchOS that gets you a device-specific identifier.

Comment: Well, I guess that settle it, there's no device-sepecific id... Thanks! I will give you the ticket.