# How to differentiate two different Apple watch programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch

I'm going to work on an apple watch application. Before jump into code, I had few question in mind.

- How to identify 2 diff. watches. IS there an unique identifier we can consume?
- If I maintain a unique identifier for each watch, when the watch connect to iPhone, how to pick a correct identifier for respective watch.
- If i do maintain some specific data handling logic for say WATCH1, and if  i pair it to new WATCH say watch 2, after some point, if i connect back to WATCH1, is there a best way to handle it.

Please help to get clear picture about these scenarios.

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: @Paulw11 We're maintaining unique identifier for each device(watch / iPhone). In standalone watch call, we need to pass this identifier to backend.

Comment: As per @arclite's answer, there is directory where you can store watch specific data but generally all watches would behave the same. You should either obtain the identifier from the phone and pass that to the server or you can generate a UUID and store that in the watch

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you please explain why we can't use `identifierForVendor` in this situation? I have looked [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205421/identifierforvendor-or-similar-for-watchos-2-0) but I can't really be sure because I have never worked in WatchOS

Comment: Because `identifierForVendor` is provided by `UIDevice` and `UIDevice` isn't part of the WatchKit frameworks

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WCSession` provides the property `watchDirectoryURL`, in which you can store data specific to a given paired watch, and this directory will change if the active watch changes.

From Apple's documentation:

> Use this directory to store preferences, files, and other data that is relevant to the specific instance of your Watch app running on the currently paired Apple Watch. If more than one Apple Watch is paired with the same iPhone, the URL in this directory changes when the active Apple Watch changes.

You can store whatever information in this directory you want, including a unique identifier that your business logic uses to detect which watch is currently active.

Comment: Thank for the answer. Let me try this. +1